# If MyMeta is the MyClass metaclass in Python 3.x, what types of manipulation can MyMeta do with MyClass?

Tags: python, reflection, metaprogramming, metaclass

The goal is to compare the power of Python metaclasses with metaprogramming systems of other languages such as Groovy, Xtend, Nemerle, CLOS, OpenJava, BSJ (BackStage Java), Iguana/J, compiler plugins for Scala, Cyan, etc.

Assume class MyMeta is the metaclass of class MyClass.

Can MyMeta generate code in MyClass that intercepts get and set of MyClass instance attributes?

Can a method of MyMeta be called when MyClass is inherited, even if the subclass metaclass is not MyMeta?

Can a method of MyMeta be called when a MyClass method is overridden in a subclass, even if the subclass metaclass is not MyMeta?

Can a method of MyMeta be called when a method of MyClass uses an attribute that has not been declared?

Can MyMeta handle the AST of MyClass or another equivalent representation?
For example, can MyMeta check if each class method has at most 20 statements? Or add a statement after the second method statement? Or rename a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can MyMeta generate code in MyClass that intercepts get and set of
>   MyClass instance attributes?

Yes. That can be done by injecting a `__getattribute__` and a `__setattr__` methods in the class. But if the attributes are declared in some other form (like, with annotations), it can also create descriptors for each attribute to handle only changes to those attributes. However, it can't trivially guess what are individual  "instance attributes" if those are just defined in the classic way, of being set in code, inside the class' `__init__` (but the first approach covers all attributes anyway);

> Can a method of MyMeta be called when MyClass is inherited, even if
>   the subclass metaclass is not MyMeta?

A subclass will automatically inherit the MyMeta as their metaclasses. If there is a conflict due to other bases, when using multiple inheritance, having other metaclasses, the subclass can't be created at all. (Unless one creates a suitable metaclass that inherits from both metaclasses, that is). _TL;DR: yes. and no,there is no subclass with a different metaclass than its parents'.

> Can a method of MyMeta be called when a MyClass method is overridden
>   in a subclass, even if the subclass metaclass is not MyMeta?

There is no such a thing as "subclass's metaclass not being MyMeta". And then, 
the metaclass acts on the subclass creation and can detect method overrides. And, it can even be made to detect method overrides by monkey-patching after the class is created (by having the metaclass implement `__setattr__`)

> Can a method of MyMeta be called when a method of MyClass uses an
>   attribute that has not been declared?

Yes, by setting suitable `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` methods as given earlier. There is no ready-made functionality for this (and no need for a metaclass as well, just a mixin implementing both methods would work)

> Can MyMeta handle the AST of MyClass or another equivalent
>   representation? For example, can MyMeta check if each class method has
>   at most 20 statements? Or add a statement after the second method
>   statement? Or rename a method?

The metaclass is called way after the AST has been created and baked into bytecode. But it can introspect into the methods bytecode to check anything it wants, and it can fetch their source code (if available), and re-generate the AST, and it can recreate other methods to replace the original ones - the substitutes having all-new bytecode. 
That kind of thing, however is rarely, if ever used and sounds like overkill.

A more pythonic approach would be to use decorators, and use the metaclass to auto-apply decorators on methods. These decorators can provide wrapper functions to run preamble and post-call code for each of the methods if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jsbueno for your very detailed answer. I appreciate that because it will be useful in an article on the Metaobject Protocol of the Cyan language (cyan-lang.org).

Comment: >A subclass will automatically inherit the MyMeta as their >metaclasses. 

But the subclass metaclass can inherit from the superclass metaclass, as is shown in [this example](https://repl.it/@JosGuimares/LightsalmonIdolizedMemoryallocator). And the subclass metaclass can redefine everything concerning the superclass metaclass. The effect is the same as if a different metaclass were used. Therefore, I suppose there is no certain way of calling a metaclass method whenever the class is inherited. Is that correct?

Comment: For the same reason, I suppose there is no certain way of calling a metaclass method whenever a class method is overridden in a subclass. Is this correct?

Comment: Isn´t __setattr__ used only for attributes? Can it be used to detect method overrides as you wrote?

Comment: If there is a sub-metaclass specifically designed to "counter" a base metaclass it inherits, then, it is obviously, possible to avoid anything on that base metaclass to take effect. But you are down to an arms race here, lke if the programmer of thesubclasses want to hide things from a metaclass police state. Outside of code-golfing or somthing, that does not make sense.

Comment: Attributes and methods in Python behave in the same way regarding assignemnts and retrieving. Both have to go through `__setattr__`  and `__getattribute__`.

Comment: as for the "guarranteed" method execution on the metaclass - as I said, if one is actively trying to avoid the base metaclass, they will succeed. To ensure metaclass code is run even if one overrides a couple things in a sub-metaclass by accident are another. You still can change teh `__call__` of the metaclass of your metaclass, for example, to make sure any specific version of your `__new__` in the metaclass is called. And you can also inject a `__init_subclass__` on the created classes with the same purpose. An "attacker" avoiding your metaclass would have to defeat both.

Comment: (you can upvote and accept the answer as well - while I appreciate the thanks in words, the comment system is better used to clarify the answers and other comunication)